# Batch file make a website to homepage in all browsers

Tags: web, batch-file

I've been looking for how to do this but failed.

I want a batch file to change the homepage for all my browsers (IE, Firefox and Chrome) at the same time may be?

I hope I can help, thanks!

Comment: And where are you stuck? Don't you how to change the homepage, or is changing it from a batch file the problem?

Comment: I've been looking for codes, but apparently do not work or do not like look, you help me?
I've been looking for codes, but apparently do not work or do not like look, you help me?
I want a small program I change the homepages of my browsers, like antivirus avira and your toolbar

Comment: Try to split your problem. First choose one browser and work on that first. Your current question is too broad, ask separate questions for the subtasks. And I don't have a toolbar....

Comment: The truth is not as a look.

There are programs that put the first ask to install www.example.com main page in browsers.

I do the same with a script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In Internet Explorer:**

you can do that like below:

```
REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main" /V "Start Page" /D "http://www.google.com/" /F
```

**In Firefox:**

FF uses a JavaScript (prefs.js in your FireFox User Profile) and not a Registry entry.

What you will need to do is programmatically edit the prefs.js file in the user profile for Firefox found in the directory C:\Users\ [USERNAME]\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\ [Subfolder]

You will need to add or edit the line that looks like: user_pref("browser.startup.homepage", "www.google.com"); as:

```
@Echo off

taskkill /im firefox.exe* /f

cd /D "%APPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles"
cd *.default
set ffile=%cd%
echo user_pref("browser.startup.homepage", "https://www.google.com");>>"%ffile%\prefs.js"
set ffile=
cd %windir%
```

**Another option using JavaScript is:**

You can change the Firefox homepage by setting the preference "browser.startup.homepage"

The easiest way to do this in an add-on via JavaScript is:

```
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm");

Services.prefs.setCharPref("browser.startup.homepage", "http://www.google.com");
```

**In Google chrome:**

chrome settings are in %USERPROFILE%\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\User Data.ChromotingConfig.json and are a little bit encrypted.

but you can do a workaround like by just pasting following javascript into the "Home Page" pref field (under your Chrome options) and it works as expected when clicking the "Home" button.

```
javascript:(function(){ window.location.href='http://www.google.com/';})();
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a Batch file with

REG ADD "HKCU\SOFTWARE\MICROSOFT\INTERNET EXPLORER\MAIN" /V "START PAGE" /D "https://google.com/" /F

Double click it will make homepage in Internet explorer